# When focus on the edite text resize layout

Tags: android, android-layout

when i press on the edit text the layout become re-size. What i want is not to change the layout size when i press on the keyboard

I tried

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

Refer from below link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Don't make any difference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#bbbbbb"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:background="#0486CC" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".34"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".32" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".16"
        android:background="@drawable/newmenu"
        android:onClick="MenuStaffBtnClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".18"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_sync"
        android:onClick="MenuSynBtnClick" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".2" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNamecheck"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:ems="10"

        android:hint="Name" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgSearch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LVitems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#bbbbbb"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to keep layout in a ScrollView(as root element) .

Comment: brother i have tested your xml its not resize the lauout

Comment: @RavindMaurya : Hi It happens for small screens

Answer (score 0):

try this layout code and add android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"  in android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

     >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrolllayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
             >
             <TextView 

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="SignIn"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:textSize="20dp"


                 />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/userid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                       android:textColor="#000000"
                android:hint="type username" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="type password"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"

                android:inputType="textPassword" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/loginid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
                   android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
                android:text="Signin"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/btngradient"

                />
              <Button android:id="@+id/registerid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
              android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text=" Register"
                android:gravity="center"
               android:background="@drawable/btngradient"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: actually somebody already told use scroll view.So just I provided  code